# How to hide 'x' on lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css

I'm using [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) to handle date changes on my new app. The problem is that 'x' that is close to the scroll.

[image]

When the users clicks on it, it erases the current value for that input. I have workaround in order to don't call my function on the controller, but visually speaking, it's very wrong to display a button that it isn't supossed to be there and actually work (on my process, of course).

I tried to search on the docs and also on the html of the component but haven't find anything that could help me... is there a way to hide this 'x' thing? I mean, if it is not displayed when there is no value for it, it has to be a way, right?

I'm going to put some code here...

Component.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="dates" type="String[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.dates}" var="date">
        <lightning:input type="date" label="date2" name="date2" aura:id="date-id" value="{!date}" onchange="{!c.fldChanged}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newDates = ["25/07/2017", "26/07/2017", "27/07/2017"];
        console.log(newDates);
        component.set("v.dates",newDates);
        console.log(component.get("v.dates"));
    },
    fldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {        
            console.log('fldChanged was called');
    }
 })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Hi @SebastianKessel, I added a example here.

Comment: For a richer date experience I would check out Lightning Strike: http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeDatepicker. It's open source too so you can make some tweaks if you need to.

Comment: Nice tip @dsharrison, I didn't knew about it, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This field is actually an Html5 [input type="date"](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

if you would like a different behavior, I would suggest you add the html5 input field type directly within your iteration:

```
<input type="date"/>
```

and scoping the css accordingly, with the webkit-clear-button in the components style:

```
.THIS::-webkit-clear-button {

    display: none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks @glls, you answer helped me a lot! I just used the same css with the lightning:input and it worked!